# Program that will have the user input

Tags: java, recursion, input

```
package state;
import java.util. Scanner;
public class State {
```

*emphasized text*
enter code herestrong text
//create a program with a user input**strong text**
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner tuwa1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Number");
//User input
callMyself(10);
}
/* The recursive Java method */
public static void callMyself(long i) {
if (i < 0) {
return;
}
System.out.print(i);
i = i - 1;
callMyself(i);

```
        int number1 = tuwa1.nexInt();
        System.out.println()
      }
    }
```

Comment: Refer to the documentation of cout. You can print multiple variable in a single line i.e cout<<var1<<var2;

Comment: @Joshua Scalercio You can even write a whole program in one line.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Not sure you can if it has output. Sure you can write `int main(){return 1;}`  but writing to the console takes at least two lines.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think you mean statements instead of lines. You can write for example int main() { int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, result = bool( std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n' ); } Here is one statement in one line.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Needs an #include, and that needs to be on its own line. Damn preprocessor!

Answer (score 1):

The program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

    std::cout <<
        "The values of the variables are " <<
        a << ", " << b << " and " << c << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

will print all three variables in a single line of output, using only a single statement. The output will be the following:

```
The values of the variables are 1, 2 and 3.
```

The statement

```
std::cout <<
    "The values of the variables are " <<
    a << ", " << b << " and " << c << ".\n";
```

can also be written as a single line, if that is a requirement of your exercise.

```
std::cout << "The values of the variables are " << a << ", " << b << " and " << c << ".\n";
```

Comment: Okay Thanks man Andreas Wenzel